# "Optimize" find clustering by local optimization

Tags: cluster-analysis, reference-request

There is a method of clustering in Mathematica named "Optimize" which find clustering by local optimization. Here is the ref http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PartitioningDataIntoClusters.html

But contrary to KMeans or KMedoids methods I could not find any mathematically rigorous description of Optimize method. Could anyone give me the reference to the mathematical description of this clustering method?

Comment: Perhaps in `http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClusterAnalysis.html` you might find some referneces